# Make downloadable product link auto selected on product page Magento

Tags: php, magento

Hi i have downloadable products on my site, there is a required field (a checkbox) on the product page.  The customer has to select the check-box every time before they can add to cart.   I want to checkbox auto selected so the customer doesn't have to check it manually.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: @sberry thanks for correction ,have any idea how can i do this ?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with magento, but I am sure you can use some simple javascript to select the box by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can set "Links can be purchased separately" to No to remove the checkbox:

[image: magento backend]

You'll get this:

[image: magento frontend]

This might not be desirable if you're just looking for a way to set a default instead of forcing it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the checkbox is from a product option? Magento does not support default values for them but there is an extension for it: [Magento Configurable Product Default Options Extension](http://icebergcommerce.com/software/magento-configurable-product-default-options-extension.html)

It is not free but in contrast to other solutions you find on the web it works without any modification to the core.

Comment: thanks for nice reply, i don't want to remove the checkbox but want it preselected if possible

Comment: huh? My answer has nothing to do with removing. Preselect a checkbox of a product option technically means providing a default option value of "1".

Comment: yes thats what i want to make it default 1, do you know how can it is possible?

Comment: It is not trivial to do so in a clean way, that's why there is a $169 extension for it.